# I would like to change the collapsible toolbar image as a particular fragment is selected like how it is in google play store

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am confused as to what it is called or what reference can i use. can you help me with some reference or how to achieve that.

When you visit play store. There are two fragments. App & Games. and Entertainment. When clicked on Entertainment. the image changes of the collapsible toolbar. when clicked on app & Games. the image changes. How to achieve that

Comment: Anyone? I really need help

Comment: not clear what you are asking for. Could you edit and provide more details?

Comment: When you visit play store. There are two fragments. App & Games. and Entertainment. When clicked on Entertainment. the image changes of the collapsible toolbar. when clicked on app & Games. the image changes. How to achieve that